# Manually add "verimatrix view right" plugin in Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, firefox, plugins, firefox-extensions

Guys I hope someone kind over here can help me add a plugin called "Verimatrix ActiveX" or "verimatrix view right" to my Mozilla Firefox on my Ubuntu 20.04.

The service provider here in Pakistan, the Pakistan Telecommunication Company wants me to add the above mentioned plugin to my Firefox browser on my Ubuntu 20.04 to enable it to play its tv service that I subscribe to. The link for TV is [www.smarttv.com.pk](http://www.smarttv.com.pk) and the plugin package is at this link http://epg16.smarttv.com.pk/iptvepg/frame1014/plug/ViewRightWeb-3.7.0.0.pkg

I do not wish to go to Windows. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to install an extension from a file. You can do this in Firefox (currently v83) using [these steps](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-and-install-add-ons-add-features-to-firefox):

- Go to your Firefox Add-ons Manager: settings > Add-ons, or use the address `about:addons`.
- Click on the gear icon on the right ("Tools for add-ons")
- Select "Install Add-on from File..." and point it to your extension.

I could not find any other Firefox extension for ActiveX. :-/ Note that this a rather old technology developed by Microsoft, which is not even supported in the latest Microsoft Edge browser: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX